# Does a case of the Empty set, make this statement vacuously true?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Let K be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (The real numbers)

Statement:

John likes $K$ if and only if $∃ a∈\mathbb{R}$ such that $∀ x∈K , a ≤ x$

Question: Does John like all subsets of the real numbers?

My thinking:
I think that john does like all subsets of the real numbers, even if the subset $K$ was to be an empty set. This is because the if the subset was to be an empty set, there would be no elements in the empty set, thus making it vacuously true. so that would mean john does like all subsets of the real numbers.

Is this correct, Does john like all subsets of the real numbers, even if the subset was an empty set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

John indeed likes the empty set. Your reasoning about that is correct. But he does not like all subsets of $\mathbb R$. He only likes subsets that have a lower bound in $\mathbb R$. E.g. he does not like $\mathbb R$.

Comment: How would you go about proving this statement using an arbitrary set?

Comment: What exactly do you mean. Do you mean the statement that John only likes subsets that have a lower bound in $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I was referring to the statement 'John likes K....' and how you would go about proving that he does not like all subsets of the real numbers

Comment: You can say that no $a\in\mathbb R$ exists with $a\leq x$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$. This because $a\leq x$ is not true for $x=a-1\in\mathbb R$. So John does not like set $\mathbb R$ wich is a subset of $\mathbb R$.