# How would you prove this statement?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

Let $K$ be a subset of $\Bbb R$ (The real numbers)

Statement:

John likes $K$ if and only if $\exists a\in\Bbb R$ such that $\forall x\in K, a \le x$

Question: Does John like all subsets of the real numbers?

My answer: Yes he does, because I cannot think of a set that will prove this do be false. There always exits a real number which is going to be smaller than any real number in the set $K$.

How would I prove my answer?

Comment: What if the subset is unbounded?

Comment: What if $K=R$ ?

Comment: Wouldn't it still be true since the lowest number will be equal to each other even if there is nothing smaller?

Comment: Ha! But unbounded set may noy have a smallest element.

Comment: I'm curious who John is. And why he prefers some subsets of $\Bbb R$ to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view these statements as a game. You go first; you choose a number $a\in\Bbb R$. Then, I choose a number $x\in K$. You win if $a\le x$; I win otherwise.

If you have a winning strategy for $K$, then John likes $K$.

Here's an example: $K=[0,1]$, the set of numbers between $0$ and $1$. On your turn, you choose $a=-1$. On my turn, *no matter what $x$ I pick,* we have $a\le x$ and you win! (Remember that $x\in K$.) So John likes $[0,1]$.

On the other hand, let $K=\Bbb R$. On your turn, you can pick anything — let's say you pick $a=-1000$. Then I can simply pick $x=-1001$, and you lose. In fact, there is no winning strategy for you! John doesn't like $\Bbb R$.

Other things that John doesn't like: $\Bbb Z$, $(-\infty,0]$, $\Bbb Q$, etc. Basically, John likes it iff it has a lower bound.

Comment: Note that the order of the quantifiers matters. If it were "$\forall x\in K$, $\exists a\in\Bbb R$ such that $a\le x$" — which is equivalent to _me_ going first — every subset works.

Comment: Does john like the empty set?

Comment: [Yes.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1462434/does-a-case-of-the-empty-set-make-this-statement-vacuously-true) Specifically: Let's say you choose $a=0$. Now, it's my turn; I have to choose an element of $K$, the empty set. I immediately lose, because no matter what number I choose, it's not in the empty set. @Mat

Comment: @Mat Note that it says $\exists a\in\Bbb R$ here. In [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1464511/does-the-empty-set-satisfy-this-statement), it says $\exists a\in K$, which is very different.

Comment: One last confusion. What if the statement was rewritten as: John likes K if and only if ∃a∈K such that ∀x∈K, a≤x    -->  K is an empty set. Will John still like the empty set? @AkivaWeinbergercolumbu

Comment: No. Anything starting with $\exists a\in\varnothing$ is false, as there is nothing in the empty set. (With that rule, John likes anything with a minimum. So $\varnothing$ and $(0,1)$ don't work, but $\{1\}$ and $[0,1]$ do.) @Mat

Answer (score 2):

Consider the case where $K=\mathbb{Z}$. Can you find an $a$ such that $a$ is less than or equal to all of the integers?

Comment: Thank you, I believe I get it now

Answer (score 2):

$\bf HINT:$

Let me rephrase your statement a bit:

$P(K):$

$\exists a \in \Bbb R\forall x\in  {K} :a\leq x$.

Now, if $K= \Bbb R$, for the proposition to be true, we have to exhibit a real number that is smaller than any other real number, can you find such an element?

Comment: Did you mean $\exists a\in\Bbb R$?

Comment: Also, YoQuieroSuLCD.

Comment: @AkivaWeinbergercolumbus Yes, of course, thanks. Haha, I bet my name's a bit funny for all spanish-speakers.

Comment: Does John like the empty set?@AkivaWeinbergercolumbus @YoTengoUnLCD