# Does the empty set satisfy this statement?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, quantifiers

Let K be the subset of |R (real numbers:

Statement:

John likes K if and only if ∃a∈K such that ∀x∈K, a < x

Question: 
Does John like any subset of the real numbers?

My answer: John will not like any subset of the real numbers. This is because regardless of what subset there is, there will never be an element 'a' in the subset K that is less than all the elements in the subset K.

My confusion was: What if the subset was an empty set. Since there are no elements in the empty set, will it make this statement vacuously true? If it does, does that mean John does like the empty set?

Comment: $\exists x \in \emptyset$ is always false.

Comment: sorry, in the statement a<x was not there previously. I just fixed it

Comment: since ∃x∈∅ is always false, does that make the statement vacuously true? @AloizioMacedo

Comment: On the contrary. John likes $K$ if and only if $\exists a \in K$ s.t. ... you can stop right there. The right side is false for $\emptyset$, therefore John doesn't like the $\emptyset$.

Comment: What Aloizio says is absolutely right and so is your answer. The statement "there will never be an element 'a' in the subset K that is ..." is true for K=∅ regardless of what you place on the ellipsis in that sentence.

Comment: So are you saying that he does not like the empty set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $k=\emptyset$, we have $\exists a \in \emptyset\,\forall x \in \emptyset\,(a<x)$. This is equivalent to $\exists a[a\in \emptyset \land \forall x \in \emptyset\,(a < x)]$. Because $a\in \emptyset$ is a always false, $a\in \emptyset \land \forall x \in \emptyset\,(a < x)$ is always false. Thus $\exists a[a\in \emptyset \land \forall x \in \emptyset\,(a < x)]$ is false, so John does not like the empty set.

Also note that no nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$ can have an element less than all elements in that subset because no $x\in\mathbb{R}$ can be less than itself.

Comment: I fixed $x<a$ to be $a<x$.

Comment: Since John does like the empty set, it means that my statement earlier 'John does not like any subset of the real numbers' is false right?

Comment: @HenryElliott: you are misinterpreting $\exists x \in X \phi(x)$: it is a shorthand for $\exists x(x\in X \land \phi(x))$, not $\exists x(x \in X \Rightarrow \phi(x))$. (John in the question does not like the empty set, because it has no  members.)

Comment: @RonArathan: right you are. I looked it up, and I confused it with with $\forall x \in A(P(x)) = \forall x (x \in A \implies P(x))$

Comment: It is fixed now.